# Issue with Samsung S5 Music player

Tags: settings

My Samsung S5 music player no longer shows the track alphabet on the right side on my screen. How to get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into phone settings>application manager>music>storage>clear cache. The press the back button and press force stop. See if that helps. If not, go to where you cleared cache, and press on 'clear data'

Comment: Sorry that didn't work and I will not "clear data", that would erase everything I've recorded.

Comment: The only thing clearing data should erase is settings and playlists. No music or recordings will be deleted, unless you found a way to record voice in the music app. If you didn't yet, you should reboot your phone. If that doesn't help, you can try uninstalling updates (you might not be able to re-download updates so see if it's worth it) just to clarify you are using the stock s5 music player and in the artist tab there are no letters to press on in order to skip to artists staying with that letter, correct?